# Records from sql database are not displaying on datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

So i have a problem with displaying the records from my data base. My Form only has two datagrids. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testare_selectie
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter daVendors = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataAdapter daInvoices = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;integrated security = TRUE");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand slctVendors = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Developerss ",cs);
            daVendors.SelectCommand = slctVendors;
            daVendors.Fill(ds,"Developerss");

            SqlCommand slctInvoices = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Games", cs);
            daVendors.SelectCommand = slctInvoices;
            daVendors.Fill(ds, "Games");

            dgV.DataSource = ds.Tables["Developerss"];
            dgI.DataSource = ds.Tables["Games"];
        }
    }
}
```

Also i would like to mention that i had previously done a project before this, that also had a display button and it worked, i'm not sure why this one isn't. I followed up a tutorial from youtube. I checked so many times for typoes or connection parameters i just can't seem to figure this out.

Thank you in advance !

video source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_K__V0rIz4

Comment: Missing your dgV.DataBind() and dgI.DataBind()?

Comment: the guy didn't add it :( . plus i didn't add it to my previous project when i displayed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms DataGridView don't need a dataBind. so that part is correct. If the data is not getting displayed, check the following:

1. data exists in the source table. (straight query OR SQL profiler results for true indication)
2. check visibility of data grid view.
3. breakpoint on ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count
4. check if the Form1_Load method is truly called. Check the Form's properties to see the Load event hookup.

that should point to the true cause.

Comment: is the Form1_Load hooked up then? maybe the event handler is not being invoked at all. Try double clicking on the form's title bar to see if it creates a new event handler or goes into this same method.

Comment: Yes that seemed to fix it! Thank you so much!